# How to get a better error message from Meteor in the case of an invalid DB update on a 'unique' indexed field?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I've set a unique index on one of my `Meteor.users` fields:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  Meteor.users._ensureIndex('profile.uri', {unique: 1, sparse: 1});
});
```

I'm allowing users to edit this field via a front-end form.

When they attempt to update it to something already taken by another user, the app - as it should - throws an error and prevents the update.

*However*, the error I'm getting is just a blank 500 Internal server error:

> M…r.m…e.errorClass {error: 500, reason: "Internal server error",
>   details: undefined, message: "Internal server error [500]", errorType:
>   "Meteor.Error"}

Which… isn't hugely useful for client-side error reporting.
How can I get Meteor to return a more precise error message so that I can appropriately interpret the cause of the error and report it to the user?

Naturally if I apply an error message specific to that error ("URI already taken") to the 500 response then it'll show for *any* 500 error, which could end up causing confusion if something else is causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be one temporary solution. Update through a method, and check in the body of that method if the specific field already exists in the collection.
I guess you could also do that in a `update` allowing hook.

Yes, it is doing again what is already done by the DB (except the DB is probably doing it better).
I can't see any other solution to have the right error message.

```
Meteor.methods({
  updateProfileUri : function(newUri) {
    if(!this.userId) {
      throw new Meteor.Error('user not signed-in');
    }

    check(newUri, String);

    //If another user already uses this URI
    if( Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: { $ne: this.userId }, 'profile.uri' : uri }) ) {
      throw new Meteor.Error('uri already taken');
    }

    updateUriOfUser(this.userId, newUri);
  }
});
```

Comment: I am already using a server-side method to process the update, so slipping this in isn't a huge issue - but as you say does feel a bit redundant!

Comment: @NathanHornby What I am afraid of is that the issue comes from the Mongo driver, or even beyond - One would have to check what kind of error is raised by Mongo (for example, "unique index duplication") and see if it is poorly sanitized anywhere (Mongo driver, ...). I don't have nearly enough knowledge on this topic to give a more detailed explanation unfortunately.

Comment: No problem @Kyll - I've added an issue over on Github - hopefully it gets a response - as this can't be the first time a Meteor user has run up against this. But you're right, in that the error is generated by Mongo itself, as you can see it in the terminal - I'm assuming that in these cases Meteor just throws a generic error, i.e. it's not specific to this issue. Fingers crossed there's a way to hook into the mongo error itself - as it is there.

Comment: Prevents the check from including the current user (who for every subsequent update would fail the condition): `Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: { $ne: Meteor.userId() }, 'profile.uri' : uri})`